# How to add custom fields in WordPress Programmatically with value 0

Tags: wordpress

I did google but don't know how to give o value atomatically a

add_post_meta(0, key , on publish)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can this function 
Will add o value on post publish

```
function add_custom_field_automatically($post_ID) {    global $wpdb;
  if(!wp_is_post_revision($post_ID)) {
  add_post_meta($post_ID, '_my_key', '0', true);
}
}
add_action('publish_page', 'add_custom_field_automatically');
 add_action('publish_post', 'add_custom_field_automatically');
```

This will automatically add a custom field

Answer (score 1):

```
function add_custom_field_automatically($post_ID) { global $wpdb;
if(!wp_is_post_revision($post_ID)) {
add_post_meta($post_ID, '_my_key', '0', true);
}
}
add_action('publish_page', 'add_custom_field_automatically');
add_action('publish_cystom_post_type', 'add_custom_field_automatically'
```

Comment: I have no idea where'd it will work or not